# .removeClass doesn't work how addClass does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive me for being a noob, but shouldn't this work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
       $(this).addClass('button-clicked');
    });

    $('.button-clicked').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('button-clicked');
    });

});
```

Shouldn't the second click remove the class and take it back to .button?

Here it is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pXdwM/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no, because at the point you're calling the second `click()` the button doesn't have ".button-clicked" and therefore event handler is not assigned. You could rewrite it like this

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('button-clicked');
});
```

or use `live()`

```
$('.button-clicked').live("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('button-clicked');
});
```

Comment: Also, even if he used `.button` as the selector, **both** click handlers would run one after the other, effectively adding and removing the class for every click. (Just commenting on the code inside the question.)

Comment: Awesome, now I get it! I'm not even going to pretend to know what .live() does, but I understand .toggleClass, so I'll use that. Thanks man.

Comment: @yatman , .live will bind events of future elements, for all the elements added at run time if we want to bind we have to use .live

Comment: So, using stereofrog's example, .live() will make it so that whenever button-clicked is clicked, it'll remove its class?

Answer (score 2):

You are adding an event to each element with class '.button-clicked', but the class does not apply until you actually click. So you need to move the second listener into the first callback, or use the `toggleClass` function:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('button-clicked');
});
```